# Binary Concatenation not Working

Tags: c, math, binary

I am currently working on a project in C and I am running into some issues when I am trying to concatenate some binary numbers.

```
uint64_t IMM = vmicxtFetch4Byte(processor, thisPC+2);
uint64_t shiftedInstr = ((uint64_t) instr16) << 32;
uint64_t instr48 = IMM | shiftedInstr;

printf("Instr16: %x IMM: %lx Instr64: %lx\n", instr16, (unsigned long) IMM, (unsigned long) instr48);
```

Now the output I get for the Immediate value (IMM) and the initial instruction (instr16) are correct but the OR'd result doesn't seem to be giving me what I want. I expect 068200000040 but i get

Instr16: 682 IMM: 40 Instr64: 40

I have done this sort of binary math a lot and for some reason this is tripping me up. Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with output, not with the computation. You cast the converted value of `instr48` to `unsigned long`, which appears to be a 32-bit type on your system. The most significant portion of `instr48` gets "sliced off", so you get the value that consists of only the least significant part.

You should cast it to `unsigned long long` instead, and use `%llu` format specifier.

Answer (score 2):

To get "068200000040" from `instr48` code needs

1. Leading 0 in print specifier
2. Print width of 12.
3. Matching specifier sequence which for `uint64_t` is found in `#include <inttypes.h>`

   ```
   #include <inttypes.h>
   printf("Instr64: %012" PRIx64 "\n", instr48);
   ```